# "undefined method `call' for #"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Rails 3 running on Apache 2 Server, and it sometimes without any reason it raise this error 
"undefined method `call' for #"
and when restart Apache by
service httpd restart
it works
please, any idea why it raise this error ?
Thanks

Comment: Can add more details to the question. Maybe add snippet of apache log and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're looking at this in a web browser and the # is just the start of something like

```
#<User id: 1, username: ... >
```

Also worth nothing that stack overflow itself will mess that up unless its in code blocks. So it could be that you added more information that the SO rendering has "swallowed".

Anyway that will help you start, but you haven't begun to give enough information for anyone to help with the actual error.